# Doсker image not starting on same port

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose

I have 2 web APi project in my solution, I am trying to start them on docker contains, but for some reason the catalog.api image fails to start on port 8000, on the very first run it was able to start on port 8000, but after I added basket.api on port 8001, the catalog api gives me an error. All my other dockers are able to restart on the same port again, only the catalog.api container doesn't start back on the port 8000.

> ERROR: for catalog.api  Cannot start service catalog.api: Ports are
> not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8000: bind: An attempt was made to
> access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

I don't see the port 8000 being used anywhere but still the api fails to start on this port, I can start the api on another port other than 8000, but I need to understand why isn't it starting on 8000 itself.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -an|find /i "8000"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8000              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

below is my docker-compose.override.yml

```html
version: '3.4'

services:
catalogdb:
    container_name: catalogdb
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site:/data/db
    ports:
        - "27017:27017"

basketdb:
    container_name: basketdb
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"

catalog.api:
    environment:
        - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        - "CatalogDatabaseSettings:ConnectionString=mongodb://catalogdb:27017"
    depends_on:
        - catalogdb
    volumes:
        - ${HOME}/.microsoft/usersecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
        - ${HOME}/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https/
    ports:
        - "8000:80"

basket.api:
    environment:
        - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        - "ConnectionStrings:Redis=basketdb:6379"
    depends_on:
        - basketdb
    volumes:
        - ${HOME}/.microsoft/usersecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
        - ${HOME}/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https/
    ports:
        - "8001:80"
```

Answer (score 0):

As I read from your docker-compose file, you are trying to map catalog.api and basket.api services both on the same port 80. This is a conflict. I think, you should map catalog.api 8000 to 8000 and basket.api 8001 to 8001 so your endpoints are not conflicting on the host machine (that is localhost I suppose here).

If you do that, you should then be able to access catalog.api at `localhost:8000` and basket.api at `localhost:8001`

So basically, both the services can't be accessed on the same port.